# Making sure that the design matrix is positive (semi-) definite

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian, covariance, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

In Bayesian linear regression, how do I make sure that the design matrix produced by a neural network $ \Phi$ is positive definite?

Computing the covariance matrix on the weight requires inverting --- i.e., $(\Phi^\text{T}\Phi)^{-1}$.  For reference, the posterior on the weights follows: $\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(m_N,S_N)$ and prior  $\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\alpha^{-1}I)$

$S_N^{-1} = \beta \cdot (\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1} + \alpha \cdot I$ where $\beta$ is the noise precision on output.

$m_N = \beta \cdot S_N \cdot \Phi^\text{T} \cdot t$ where $t$ is the target on seen data.

Comment: When $\Phi$ is *any* matrix, $\Phi^\prime\Phi$ is *always* positive semidefinite.  (Proof: for any vector $x,$ $x^\prime(\Phi^\prime\Phi)x = ||\Phi x||^2$ is the square of a real number.) In practice, accumulation of floating point roundoff errors may sometimes make it appear not to be PSD by introducing extremely tiny negative eigenvalues: those can be treated as zeros.  Note that semi-definite matrices are not necessarily invertible, anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Shouldn't it in this case require that $\Phi$ to have full rank? https://www.math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Lectures/Lecture33_with_Examples.pdf (Pg. 4)

Comment: Full rank is unnecessary: consider the case where $\Phi$ is the zero matrix, for instance.  It's still positive-semidefinite (obviously!).  Your reference refers to positive-definite matrices, not positive-semidefinite ones (as specified in the title to your question).

Comment: I am using a wide shallow network on low dimensional input to build this design matrix. I could solve the issue by reducing the number of output neurons from 100 to 80.

Comment: the premise of this question is mistaken: $S_N^{-1} = \beta\Psi^\top\Psi + \alpha \mathbf{I}$, not $\beta(\Psi^\top\Psi)^{-1} + \alpha \mathbf{I}$, i.e. the Bayesian prior precision is added to $\beta\Psi^\top\Psi$ *before* inversion, not after. The posterior thus has a full rank covariance even if the data don't (so long as the prior does). (Wikipedia's article has a derivation of this).

Answer (score 1):

If you want $(\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}$ to be invertible (where $\Phi \in R^{N \times K})$ you need to ensure $rk(\Phi) = K$ (i.e. full rank). As mentioned in the comments, if $\Phi$ is rank deficient then $\Phi^T\Phi$ is *positive semidefinite* and thus not always invertible.